# UV-unwrapping looks different

Tags: texturing, uv, vertices, uv-image-editor

I have 3 exact same cubes. The difference is that one cube is rotated on the z-axis. I unwrapped all of them and marked the seams exact same, but the rotated one looks different. Here is a picture:

[image]

How can I get the same UV unwrap for all cubes? Thank you for helping!

[image]

Comment: Rotation of the mesh by itself can't be the reason, there should be something else going on as well. If you can share the file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it would be easier to someone to reproduce this

Comment: ok, I have uploaded it.

Comment: Object has uneven scale; Blender most likely warned you about that in the Info editor (top bar in default screen layout). As scale is much smaller by X axis (what you see and unwrap doesn't) so the difference becomes more apparent once you rotate the mesh around world axes. Note that once applying UV map will change quite a bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple UV Mesh Unwrapping Scale issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7965/simple-uv-mesh-unwrapping-scale-issue)